# Multiple Inheritance in Python gives TypeError

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter, typeerror, multiple-inheritance

I have the following code:

```
import Tkinter
from labrad.server import LabradServer

class MyController(LabradServer,Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, var, parent=None):
        LabradServer.__init__(self)
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyController(9)
    app.title('Controller')
    app.mainloop()
```

When I run this, however, I get `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`.  I know this is from the second `__init__()` call, since I can freely print something after the `LabradServer.__init__(self)` and it will print before the error is triggered.  Any idea what is causing this, or how to fix it?

Comment: in `MyController` your `__init__` takes 3 arguments yet you only pass it two (the `MyController` instance and the integer `9`). Maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: you might also want to read about [`super()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3277407/827519) and how it's used to call base class constructors.

Answer (score 2):

`Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)` takes 1 argument, but you gave it 3. Try:

```
Tkinter.Tk.__init__()
```

instead.

Comment: This gives me the error `TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Tk instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: Are you sure you typed your initial error message correctly?